# JS Bookmarklet for Searching page source for specific code

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a JS Bookmarklet that will search the source of whatever page I'm on for a specific code (example. "G1_Value_client") and if that exists I want it to return an alert A and if it does not exist I want it to return alert B.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf('G5_CLIENT_TRACKING_ID') > -1`

Comment: The code you posted isn't JavaScript. It appears to be C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm..Javascript Bookmarklets are written in javascript, not c#. Here's a sort of translation:

```
if(document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("G5_CLIENT_TRACKING_ID") > -1) {
    alert("Core Site!");
} else {
    alert("Cloud Site!");
}
```

Comment: What is the > -1 part saying? and is it searching for that exact match thing within the quotes or is it searching for partial match? Thanks for your help Im a total newb!

Comment: The function document.documentElement.outerHTML.indexOf("G5_CLIENT_TRACKING_ID") finds the element and returns the location of the element inside the HTML document. If the location is over -1 that means it exists inside the document.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!